# XPath to select specific text inside of text block

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to figure out a way to pull specific values out of a big long text block.

So far I have //td[@class="PadLeft10"] which returns me a big long value starting with the company name and ending with the "View More Info" piece.

I am trying to break my results up into segments, so for example I want my code to look for the words "Primary Contact:" and then return the text that follows that, ending at the `<br/>`.

I need to get the Company Name, which is always the first bit of text, then the Primary Contact, then the Address, then the Phone and Fax, then the Website, and the Organization type.

The problem is that not every record has all the values. As you can see, the second entry has the address and website, but the first one doesn't.

I am using the Dataminer Chrome Plugin, for anyone familiar with that. It has separate xpath for rows and columns, so I am going to try to make a bunch of different columns that correspond to each of the fields that I am looking for.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
<td align="left" valign="top" width="2%">
<script>
    if (0 == 1) document.write('<img src="https://website.com" border="0" alt=""/>');
</script>
<br/><br/></td>
<td class="PadLeft10" align="left" valign="top" width="32%" style="padding-left: 15px;">
<span style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 12pt;"><br/>Company Name Here</span><br/>Primary Contact: Mr. Eric Cartman <br/>Phone: (555) 555-5555<br/>Fax: (333) 333-3333<span style="text-decoration: underline;color: #0000ff"></span><br/>Organization Type: Distributor Branch
<br/>
<a href="javascript:OpenNewWindow('DemographicsShow.aspx?FormKey=6546513265&Title='+escape('Company Name Here')+'&Key=654321231651');" class="DataFormHyperLink" title="Click here for more information">» View More Info</a><br/>
<br/>
</td>


<td align="left" valign="top" width="2%">
<script>
    if (0 == 1) document.write('<img src="https://website.com" border="0" alt=""/>');
</script>
<br/><br/></td>
<td class="PadLeft10" align="left" valign="top" width="32%" style="padding-left: 15px;">
<span style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 12pt;"><br/>Other Company</span><br/>Primary Contact: Mr. Jimmy Valmer<br/>100 N Ohio St 2rd Fl<br/>Rochester, IN 54225<br/>United States<br/>Phone: (888) 888-8888<br/>Fax: (999) 999-9999<span style="text-decoration: underline;color: #0000ff"><br/>Web Site: <a href="http://www.companywebsite.com" target="_blank">http://www.companywebsite.com</a></span><br/>Organization Type: Financial Service
<br/>
<a href="javascript:OpenNewWindow('DemographicsShow.aspx?FormKey=65484651534684&Title='+escape('Other Company')+'&Key=65484561534986');" class="DataFormHyperLink" title="Click here for more information">» View More Info</a><br/>
<br/>
</td>


</tr>
<tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

As far as a direction, the sections within table cell that you mention are neither nested DOM items, nor sibling-type DOM nodes. Those are *sequential html elements* that require special processing.

```
<br/>Company Name Here</span>
<br/>Primary Contact: Mr. Eric Cartman 
<br/>Phone: (555) 555-5555
<br/>...
```

Both *xpath* and *regex* can be leveraged for such a case.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.

Comment: @LibertyForLife, if you find it useful, would you check up this answer?

Answer (score 0):

I am new to xpath, but the least i can say: if you are the creator of the html code, you absolutely need to change it to be more structured
like : Primary Contact:`<span id/class='primaryContact'>..</span>`

Or else, you can get the elements by this selector (to edit) `//td[@class="PadLeft10"]//child::span//following-sibling::text()[1]` split by ':' and then proceed, but this solution stay just a diy.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not the creator... If I was, then it would definitely be more structured!

I'll try out your examples and report back. Thanks!

Comment: i recommand you to use **firepath** with **firebug** to view results faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the text node you're looking for using a predicate and the `contains` function:

```
//td[@class="PadLeft10"]/text()[contains(., "Primary Contact:")]
```

Then you can get the substring using the `substring-after` function:

```
substring-after(
    //td[@class="PadLeft10"]/text()[contains(., "Primary Contact:")],
    'Primary Contact:'
)
```

And remove leading and trailing whitespace using `normalize-space`:

```
normalize-space(
    substring-after(
        //td[@class="PadLeft10"]/text()[contains(., "Primary Contact:")],
        'Primary Contact:'
    )
)
```